Do veinlets of leaves always originate from the midrib?
When studying venation in leaves, I came upon a few diagrams of parallel venation where veinlets originated from midrib, and converged toward the midrib such that they all lay parallel to it...
But I have also seen some monocots (a palm and some grasses) whose veinlets don't look like they're emerging from the midrib at all.
So do they just emerge from the base of the lamina?
If yes, then how are they connected to the transporting vessels which are present in midrib?


